# How can I store a weather station data into a Toit metric?

Tags: toit

I have successfully followed [the tutorial to build the weather station](https://docs.toit.io/platform/tutorials/starter/weatherstation). However, I now want to store the collected data in a metric subscription. Aside the fact that [I am failing to create a subscription](https://github.com/toitware/public/issues/22), assuming I have a `temperature` metric subscription, how could I store the data there?

In other words, I want to store the `$bme.read_temperature` into the `temperature` metric so that I can then read it with `toit data read metrics temperature`

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using pubsub.
To publish the temperature to a pubsub topic do:

```
import pubsub
import encoding.json
import gpio
import i2c
import drivers.bme280 as drivers

main:
  bus := i2c.Bus
    --sda=gpio.Pin 21
    --scl=gpio.Pin 22

  device := bus.device drivers.I2C_ADDRESS_ALT

  bme := drivers.Bme280 device

  bme.on

  tmp := bme.read_temperature
  pubsub.publish "cloud:temperature" 
    json.encode {"t": tmp}
```

To read the data using the CLI, first you have to create a subscription:

```
toit pubsub subscription create cloud:temperature my-temp-sub
```

next, run the application code and try and read the temperature from the CLI using:

```
toit pubsub read cloud:temperature my-temp-sub
```

To get more information on pubsub checkout https://docs.toit.io/platform/tutorials/pubsub/pubsubext

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much